# Get document from GET request

Tags: http-get, cmis

I need your help:
I have the following method

```
   @Path("/download")
    public class FileDownloadService {

        @GET
        public Response downloadFile(@QueryParam("filenet_id") String filenet_id, @QueryParam("version") String version) {
    ...
    Document document = (Document) cmisObject;
    return Response.ok(document, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
}
```

and I want to get the document throught HTTP GET, I tried to write this code but I don't know how to get it, "output" don't conatains it:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();              
builder.setScheme("http").setHost("localhost:8080").setPath("/filenetintegration/rest/download")
    .setParameter("filenet_id", filenet_id)
    .setParameter("version", version+".0");
    URI uri = builder.build();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(uri.toString()).openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((urlConnection.getInputStream())));
    String output;
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Edit:
maybe the problem is on this line, it don't put the document inside the response:

```
return Response.ok(document, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
```

Comment: Which response code you're getting? Is it 200 ?

Comment: yes, the call works correctly but I do not know how to retrieve the document in the response

Comment: I'm not sure that calling `connect()` directly is a good idea. I would try `getResponseCode()` instead,

Comment: The problem is that I can not retrieve the document within the response. How can I get it?

Comment: You are reading the response with your BufferedReader. That InputStream is your file. So what's the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is:
return Response.ok(documentToByte(document), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this on the server side:

```
Document document = (Document) cmisObject;

ContentStream contentStream = document.getContentStream();
final InputStream stream = contentStream.getStream();

StreamingOutput output = (OutputStream out) -> {
  try {
    int b;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64*1024];

     while ((b = stream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
       out.write(buffer, 0, b);
     }
  } finally {
    try {
      stream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {}
  }
};

return Response.ok(output, contentStream.getMimeType()).build();
```